# Is a C# "constructor" the same as an Obj-C "initializer"?

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

I am very, very new to Obj-C, and will have a ton of questions.  (I have the book "iPhone Programming, The Big Nerd Ranch Guide", but it doesn't address the differences between C# and Obj-C. Does anyone know of a doc that does address the differences?).

Anyway, my question is above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C, object allocation and initialization are separate operations, but it's common and a good practice to see them called in the context of the same expression:

```
MyClass *myInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];

// ...

[myInstance release];
```

In C#, allocation and initialization happen when you use `new`:

```
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
```

The runtime allocates the instance and *then* calls the constructor.

So yes, the C# constructor is equivalent to the Objective-C initializer, but the usage is different.

Apart from this ... `init` in Objective-C is just a normal *instance* method, without any special semantics. You can call it at any point. In C#, constructors are very special *static*-like methods treated differently by the runtime and with special rules. For example, the C# compiler enforces calls to the base class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

They are similar only as much as you can compare two completely different methods for creating an object.  Checkout this information on the [Objective-C Runtime](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/03/07/ipad-2-line-has-formed-in-texas/).

The following is a very simple (but hopefully not misleading) explanation:

**Objective-C**

```
id object = [MyObject alloc]; // allocates the memory and returns a pointer.  Factory-like method from NSObject (unless your class overrides it)
MyObject *myObj = [object init]; // initializes the object by calling `-(id)init`.  You'll want to override this, or a similar init method for all your classes.
```

Usually written like this:

```
MyObject *myObj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
```

From what I know, the [C# constructor](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html) allocates the memory and calls the appropriate constructor function to initialize the object.

A difference is that in C# you can't call an inherited constructor (see the bottom of the link above) but in Obj-C this will compile, but will give you wrong results.

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
- (id) initWithInteger:(int)num;
@end
@interface ClassB : ClassA
- (id) init;
@end
@implementation ClassB
- (id) init
{
    self = [supere initWithInteger:10];
    return self;
}

// main
ClassA *a = [[ClassA alloc] initWithInteger:10]; //valid
ClassB *a = [[ClassB alloc] initWithInteger:10]; // will call init from classA, bypassing and not calling init for classB.
```

Just be careful with weak/dynamic typed language of Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

They're similar, but not identical. Technically, a constructor fully creates and initializes an instance, while an initializer takes an already constructed instance (usually gotten through `alloc`) and sets the instance up so that it's ready to be used.

As for the differences between Objective-C and C#: They're two different and mostly unrelated languages. When you're learning a new language, trying to think of it as "Like this language I already know, but with these differences" can actually make it harder to learn, because there are a *lot* of differences and they're often subtle, so going in with assumptions from another language will confuse you. If you search around Stack Overflow, you'll find a lot of PHP programmers who start to learn a new language and immediately wonder "How do I do variable variables in this language?" It's like looking for a list of the differences between English and Chinese — you're better off not trying to treat one like the other. Keep in mind what you already know, but try not to assume any of it is the same in Objective-C.